# $X,Y$ are independent random variables of the same "type". When is $Y$ the same "type" when conditioned on $X+Y=z$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

EDIT: Corrected an error in my OP.

Let $X,Y$ be independent random variables of the same "type" or "class" (see examples below), and let $Z=X+Y$.  I am interested in the conditional distribution of $Y$, conditioned on $Z=z$, which I will denote as $(Y|Z=z)$.  I noticed this:

- If $X,Y$ were independent uniform random variables, e.g. $U(x_1,x_2), U(y_1, y_2)$, then clearly for any $z, (Y|Z=z)$ is also $\sim U(a,b)$ for some $a$ and $b$ which depend on $z$, because conditioning on $Z=z$ means restricting to a $-45°$ line within the $[x_1, x_2] \times [y_1, y_2]$ rectangle.  (Note that $Z$ itself is not uniform, but triangular distributed.)
- If $X \sim N(\mu_x, \sigma^2_x), Y \sim N(\mu_y, \sigma^2_y)$ are independent Gaussians, then I believe $Y,Z$ are multivariate Gaussian (although no longer independent) and consequently $(Y|Z=z)$ (for any $z$) is still Gaussian but with different parameters (mean and sigma) that depend on $z$.  (I am not 100% sure about this, and my question on this specific case is a different post: [Gaussians and sum of Gaussians](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741829/gaussians-and-sum-of-gaussians))

So we have two examples where, $X$ and $Y$ both belong to a certain "class" (Gaussian or Uniform), and conditioned on $Z=X+Y=z$, the marginal $(Y|Z=z)$ still belong to the same class (Gaussian or Uniform), for any $z$.  Sorry I don't have a very precise definition of "class" but **how general is this phenomenon?**  Or is there something special about Uniform (based on simple geometry) or Gaussian (based on complicated proofs about properties of multivariate Gaussians)?  Note that $Z=X+Y$ does not necessarily belong to the same class (it does in case of Gaussian, but not in case of Uniform).

There are many counter-examples, and the proofs are usually simply "range" violations, such as:

- If $X, Y$ are independent $Bin(n,p)$, then $(Y|Z=z)$ is not binomial for some $z$. E.g. $z = n+1 \Rightarrow Y \ge 1$ (because $X \le n$), but no binomial r.v. (with $p < 1$) can have a range that exclude $0$.  (However I am unsure if $(Y|Z=z)$ in this case is a shifted binomial, i.e. some $Bin(n', p') +$ some constant.)
- More generally, if the "class" consists of r.v.s with range $[0, +\infty)$, then $(Y|Z=z)$ no longer belong to that class since $(Y|Z=z) \le z$ and does not have the required range to infinity.  This rules out: Poisson, exponentials, and many other classes.

So, besides Uniform and Gaussians, are there other such "classes" where if $X, Y$ belong to the class then $(Y|Z=z)$ also belong to the class, for any $z$?  And are there underlying properties that make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counter-example.  Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are exponential: $\Pr(X>t) = \Pr(Y>t) = e^{-t}$ for $t\ge 0$.  Then $\Pr(Y>t | X+Y=z) = 0$ if $t > z > 0$.

Comment: thanks.  there are lots of counter-examples, and in fact, binomials dont behave this way either -- my OP was wrong and i will correct it soon.